# Calling Method that has a Return value...param

Tags: c#, class, return

I am in search of what to put in the param for purse.CountMoney(); if anything...im having a mental block as how methods that return a value work in comparison to non returning methods...I tried total...double total....um I tried stepping into the program and see if the debug tool could assist and nothing popped out at me.

Any guidance be wonderful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace lab24
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CoinPurse purse = new CoinPurse();

        purse.AddPenny(3);
        purse.AddNickel(4);
        purse.AddDime(2);
        purse.AddQuarter(1);
        purse.CountMoney();
        purse.TakeNickels(4);
        purse.CountMoney();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public class CoinPurse
    {
        private int numPennies;
        private int numNickels;
        private int numDimes;
        private int numQuarters;
        private double total;

        public CoinPurse()
        {
            numPennies = 0;
            numNickels = 0;
            numDimes = 0;
            numQuarters = 0;
            total = 0;
        }
        public void AddPenny(int p)
        {
            numPennies += p;
        }
        public void AddNickel(int n)
        {
            numNickels += n;
        }
        public void AddDime(int d)
        {
            numDimes += d;
        }
        public void AddQuarter(int q)
        {
            numQuarters += q;
        }
        public void TakePenny(int p)
        {
            numPennies -= p;
        }
        public void TakeNickels(int n)
        {
            numNickels -= n;
        }
        public void TakeDime(int d)
        {
            numDimes -= d;
        }
        public void TakeQuarters(int q)
        {
            numQuarters -= q;
        }
        public double CountMoney(double total)
        {
            double q = numQuarters * .25;
            double d = numDimes * .10;
            double n = numNickels * .05;
            double p = numPennies * .01;

            total = q + d + n + p;

            return total;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `CountMoney` method to look like this:

```
public double CountMoney()
{
    double q = numQuarters * .25;
    double d = numDimes * .10;
    double n = numNickels * .05;
    double p = numPennies * .01;

    double total = q + d + n + p;

    return total;
}
```

You can then call it from the `Main` method like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    CoinPurse purse = new CoinPurse();

    purse.AddPenny(3);
    purse.AddNickel(4);
    purse.AddDime(2);
    purse.AddQuarter(1);
    purse.CountMoney();
    purse.TakeNickels(4);

    double total = purse.CountMoney();

    Console.WriteLine(total);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Love it! I haven't a clue why I was trying to pass that in the param. Thanks for the reality check.

Comment: We've all been there.  Don't worry about it.  Us Dans have to stick together.

Comment: =)  (empty space to allow smile face)

Answer (score 2):

```
var total = 0m;
total = purse.CountMoney(total);
```

However, this code looks a little strange, you are expected to pass in a double, only for it to be calculated and passed back out, without taking the initial value into account.

Personally, I would lose the input parameter to `CountMoney()`

```
 public double CountMoney()
        {
           //Existing Code
        }
```

and just return the double as you are doing, you could then call it directly;

```
var total = purse.CountMoney();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tell, what is the purpose of parameter `total` in your method `CountMoney`? Is it to retrieve total count of money? Then you need to specify `out` keyword and probably do not need return value, as follows:

#### # 1 (with *out* keyword)

```
    public void CountMoney(out double total)
    {
        double q = numQuarters * .25;
        double d = numDimes * .10;
        double n = numNickels * .05;
        double p = numPennies * .01;

        total = q + d + n + p;
    }
```

then method `Main` will look as follows:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        CoinPurse purse = new CoinPurse();

        purse.AddPenny(3);
        purse.AddNickel(4);
        purse.AddDime(2);
        purse.AddQuarter(1);
        purse.CountMoney();
        purse.TakeNickels(4);

        double total;
        purse.CountMoney(out total);
        Console.WriteLine(total);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Also you can do it differently (and more naturally for this case) using return value.

#### # 2 (with return value)

Method `CountMoney` with return value will look as follows:

```
    public double CountMoney()
    {
        double q = numQuarters * .25;
        double d = numDimes * .10;
        double n = numNickels * .05;
        double p = numPennies * .01;

        return q + d + n + p;
    }
```

and method `Main` will look as follows:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        CoinPurse purse = new CoinPurse();

        purse.AddPenny(3);
        purse.AddNickel(4);
        purse.AddDime(2);
        purse.AddQuarter(1);
        purse.CountMoney();
        purse.TakeNickels(4);

        Console.WriteLine(purse.CountMoney());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add (correct me if I am wrong) all types of change to get a total of your money in the purse, which wouldn't work in this case because variables will not process over initial values and hold the result. you should either utilize the ref keyword ( see the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ) or the best approach would be to utilize objects(always think object-oriented)